# BadArgumentError - The request had some invalid properties

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to get the logs from the log analytics workspace in Azure. While trying to access the workspace using Python I was getting the error as below.

When I used the `log_query = "Heartbeat"` I was getting the results successfully.

But when I use any other KQL query like below I get the error.

What could it go wrong?

```
log_query = """
Heartbeat
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| summarize count() by Computer
"""
```

**Code**

```
monitor_resource_id = "ec1e-4764-9ebf"

time_range = timedelta(days=7)

def authenticate():
    return DefaultAzureCredential()

def query_logs():
    credential = authenticate()
    try:
        logs_query_client = LogsQueryClient(credential)
        end_time = datetime.utcnow()
        start_time = end_time - time_range
        query = f"{log_query} | where TimeGenerated >= datetime({start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')}) and TimeGenerated <= datetime({end_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')})"
        timespan = (start_time, end_time)
        response = logs_query_client.query_workspace(monitor_resource_id, query, timespan=timespan)
        for table in response.tables:
            for row in table.rows:
                print(row)
    
    except HttpResponseError as e:
        print(f"HTTP Response Error: {e.message}")
        print(f"Response status code: {e.status_code}")
        print(f"Error details: {e.error}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

**Error**

```
Response status code: 400
Error details: (BadArgumentError) The request had some invalid properties
Code: BadArgumentError
Message: The request had some invalid properties
Inner error: {
    "code": "SemanticError",
    "message": "A semantic error occurred.",
    "innererror": {
        "code": "SEM0100",
        "message": "'where' operator: Failed to resolve column or scalar expression named 'TimeGenerated'"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a wild stab, but I see from some googling that there can be odd issues with blank lines.  What happens if you start your query without the newline, i.e. `log_query = """Heartbeat` with no newline following the first triple-double-quote?

Comment: It did not work @Malcolm thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66411592/build-a-heartbeat-alert-on-azure and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65002402/the-query-didnt-return-the-timegenerated-column-please-edit-the-query-and-incl appear to be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, I also got the same error by using your query. Check below:

[image]

I have used the code below to retrieve logs from the Log Analytics workspace. However, I modified the query as below:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.monitor.query import LogsQueryClient
from azure.core.exceptions import HttpResponseError

monitor_resource_id = "your workspace_id" 
time_range = timedelta(days=7)
table_name = "your-table-name" 

def authenticate():
    return DefaultAzureCredential()

def query_logs():
    credential = authenticate()
    try:
        logs_query_client = LogsQueryClient(credential)
        end_time = datetime.utcnow()
        start_time = end_time - time_range

        kql_query = f"""
        {table_name}| where TimeGenerated between (datetime(2023-12-18T10:21:48z) .. datetime(2023-12-18T12:44:56z))
| top 10 by _ResourceId
        """
        
        response = logs_query_client.query_workspace(
            monitor_resource_id,
            query=kql_query,
            timespan=(start_time, end_time)
        )
        for table in response.tables:
            for row in table.rows:
                print(row)
    
    except HttpResponseError as e:
        print(f"HTTP Response Error: {e.message}")
        print(f"Response status code: {e.status_code}")
        print(f"Error details: {e.error}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    query_logs()
```

I have successfully retrieved the logs using the "where" condition. Please check below:

**Output:**

[image]

**Azure portal:**

[image]